# Combining Query and Conditional Statement in Google Spreadsheets

Tags: arrays, if-statement, google-sheets-formula, google-query-language, nested-if

Regardiung the function below, I want this line `AND P < '"&B5&"'` to be applied everytime but not when `B3="446"`.
I'm not sure how to insert this condition in the query fnction.

```
=IFERROR(QUERY(BDD!A1:T2972;
"SELECT A,R,B,C,D,E,S,I,T,P,J,K,L 
WHERE A IS NOT NULL 
AND P < '"&B5&"' 
AND 1=1 "&IF(B2="XXXX";"";" AND LOWER(J) = LOWER('"&B2&"') ")&IF(B3="0c";"";" AND LOWER(S) = LOWER('"&B3&"') 
AND NOT(LOWER(J)='PERM' AND T='"&B3&"')
AND I = 'ADMI'
ORDER BY A , P")
;0);"PAS DE RÉSULTAT")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to replace:

```
AND P < '"&B5&"'
```

with:

```
"&IF(B3*1=446; "1=1"; "AND P < '"&B5&"'")&"
```

Comment: I tweaked it just a little bit ­­­­­["&IF(C3="446"; ""; " AND P < '"&C5&"'")&"] -- Thank you so much.